# Positional indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Here's a dataframe:

```
bacteria = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'bacteria_counts': [632, 1638, 569, 115],
        'other_feature': [438, 833, 234, 298]
    },
    index=['Firmicutes', 'Proteobacteria', 'Actinobacteria', 'Bacteroidetes'])
```

[image]

Here's a question, if I use `bacteria[2:3]`, it returns:

[image]

What's `[2:3]` representing? Rows and columns? (Just start learning about Positional indexing)

Comment: Try, when possible, to use `.iloc()` with dataframes ;-) Here's the doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html and another interesting link; https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-and-selecting-data-with-pandas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Pandas the general slicing syntax is like so:

```
[start row: up to but not including row , start column: up to but not including column]
```

Which is why in your case, seeing that you didn't provide a column argument you just got the row with the 3rd item in your index. In fact, without using a more advanced slicing method, you will likely get a traceback if you try to select columns with your current strategy.

However, most pandas slicing is doing using .iloc, and .loc. You should take a look at the docs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: You mean the standard format will be ```[row:row, column:column]```, right? Because I didn't give argument to the column part, so it returns all the colums, right?

Comment: Yes, but do yourself a favor and look into .iloc, .loc, and .at. And stay away from .ix because it's deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, just queries, when I tried ```bacteria[2:3, 1:2]```, it returns error: ```TypeError: '(slice(2, 3, None), slice(1, 2, None))' is an invalid key```

Comment: That's because you need to use the more advanced .iloc or .loc method such as bacteria.iloc[2:3, 1:2].